# Regarding cookies accessibility in virtual directories

Tags: c#, cookies, iis-7

I have 1 Application and 2 Virtual directories in IIS, I want to restrict the access of cookie between virtual directories i.e I do not want the cookie created in 1 virtual directory  to be accessed in 2nd directory. How can we prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest make use of

[HttpCookie.Path Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Gets or sets the virtual path to transmit with the current cookie.

this allows to differentiate between two virtual directory.